# View user-defined variables in Julia

Tags: julia

Perhaps this is something I've simply overlooked in the documentation, but how can you view a list of currently defined variables in Julia? For example, in R you can use `ls()` which will give you a list of user-defined objects in the current scope. Is there an equivalent in Julia?

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301451/get-a-list-of-current-variables-in-julia-lang), but it seems that the `whos` function (as well as `names`) will list modules and other things which are not *user-defined*. How do I simply list variables which have been defined by the user and are not exported from other modules?

Comment: @musically_ut: Edited to clarify my intent. It's slightly different than that question in that I'm looking to view _only_ variables which have been defined by the user rather than exported from modules.

Comment: I think you're after the behavior in this pull request: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/10108. You should add your feedback on the proposed API and help get it merged!

Comment: @MattB.: Nice, thanks for the heads up on that. I don't have write access so I can't merge the pull request but I left a comment. The API is a little weird IMO clearly I'm a fan of the functionality. ;)

Comment: Right, I simply meant that your feedback would be helpful in getting it merged, since the only remaining question there seemed to be about the API.  Thanks for doing so!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach is to make a variant of `whos` that restricts on the summary of the objects in the current module:

```matlab
function whos_user(m::Module=current_module())
    for v in sort(names(m))
        s = string(v)
        if isdefined(m, v) && summary(eval(m, v)) != "Module" && s != "whos_user"
            println(s)
        end
    end
end
```

Then if we do

```matlab
x = 1
y = "Julia"
f(n) = n + 1
whos_user()
```

we get

```matlab
f
x
y
```

One could also write `whos_user` to return an array of symbols rather than printing:

```matlab
function whos_user(m::Module=current_module())
    v = sort(names(m))
    filter(i -> isdefined(m, i) && summary(eval(m, i)) != "Module" && string(i) != "whos_user", v)
end
```

Then running the same test code as before, we get this:

```matlab
3-element Array{Symbol,1}:
  :f
  :x
  :y
```

If there's no better way to do this then I'll accept this answer.

Answer (score 5):

For Julia v0.7.0 and up, there's a nice function `varinfo`, which is more or less equivalent to MATLAB's `whos` function. `varinfo` still lists some module names like `Base`, `Core`, etc., but in a much more compact manner than Julia's old `whos` function. It also uses Markdown to render the variable table nicely, e.g.,

```
    julia> varinfo()
    name                    size summary
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––------
    Base                         Module
    Core                         Module
    InteractiveUtils 164.866 KiB Module
    Main                         Module
    Plots             21.028 MiB Module
    ans                144 bytes 13-element Array{Symbol,1}
    x                   48 bytes 20-element StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}
    y                   48 bytes 20-element StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}
    y0                 440 bytes 50-element Array{Float64,1}
    y1                 440 bytes 50-element Array{Float64,1}
    z                  3.164 KiB 20×20 Array{Float64,2}
```

Comment: That is a helpful function to know about.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Julia has [`whos` function](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=whos#Base.whos), akin to MATLAB, for this task.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to make `whos` only list variables defined by the user rather than all available modules, etc.?

Comment: It isn't exactly what you are looking for, but assuming you are working at the REPL you can try `whos(Main)`, which will only list names in the Main module.

Comment: @spencerlyon2: I tried that, but it still lists all of the modules and everything. For example, on JuliaBox, `whos(Main)` prints `ArrayViews  Module, Base Module, ...` It is getting closer though, since user-defined variables will be in there too.

Comment: Yeah, I was worried you'd have too many other things in there. I don't know of a way to narrow down to only user defined objects.

Comment: @spencerlyon2: I think I found a decent way. Posted it as an answer.