# Does Atom/Juno/Julia have an equivalent to Matlabs workspace?

Tags: julia, atom-editor, workspace

If it does how can I toggle it? I have tried to look around but cannot find anything on it. I find Matlab's Workspace very convenient as I can follow which matrices I have createdand if in fact they look as I wanted them to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I  would have added this as a comment, but don't have the reputation)

This is answered here: [Get a list of current variables in Julia Lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301451/get-a-list-of-current-variables-in-julia-lang)

You can use the `whos` function, same as in Matlab.

Julia also has a function called `workspace`, which does something completely different, a bit like Matlab's `clear all`, where you stash away the entire current workspace, but in a way so that you can retrieve it at a later point.

Comment: After thinking about it some more, are you talking about the workspace _browser_ that shows the variables in a graphical window in the IDE? In that case, Juno will probably have them in the not-too-distant future, but last I checked it was not ready yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know of whos but meant a workspace browser. That way I can follow all matrices as they are created etc. Do you know anything about how long it will be until they implement it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really know. But you can follow the discussion here: http://discuss.junolab.org/t/new-features-you-want-in-juno/494
 Workspace browser seems to be quite high on the list of wanted features.