# Get list of variables in the current namespace in Julia

Tags: variables, module, namespaces, julia

I have a question that is similar to, but different than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301451/get-a-list-of-current-variables-in-julia-lang). I have a function within a module, and I would like to see what variables are defined inside the function namespace. In the other post, they said to use `varinfo`, but that seems to only work in the Main namespace. For example if I run this

```
module Test

function hello()
    a = 1
    varinfo()
    return a
end

end

import .Test

Test.hello()
```

I get this error

```
WARNING: replacing module Test.
ERROR: UndefVarError: varinfo not defined
```

Is there a way to get a list of variables within a given namespace? What I am looking for is a function that when called, outputs all the available variables (a in my example) as well as available modules within the namespace.

PS. I would like to add, that `varinfo` is incredibly limiting because its output is a Markdown.MD, which cannot be iterated over. I would prefer a function that outputs variables and values in some sort of list or dictionary if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varinfo` is showing only the global variables.
If you want the local variables, you need to use the `Base.@locals` macro:

```
module Test
    function hello()
        a = 1
        println(Base.@locals)
        return a
    end
end
```

And now you can do:

```
julia> Test.hello()
Dict{Symbol, Any}(:a => 1)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
module Test

function hello()
    a = 1
    println(Main.varinfo(@__MODULE__; all=true, imported=true))
    return a
end

end
```